# Client side validation issue on partial view

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, partial-views, unobtrusive-validation

I am working on client side validation on partial view. I am trying to render jaqueryval bundle on master page but its not working.

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
```

In case same bundle render on partial view it works.

I would like to know how I can achieve the same, any small inputs on the same is also greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have a bundle called jqueryval or is jqueryval located in the jquery bundle?

Comment: Also, are the elements you are trying to validate added dynamically?

Comment: add the following after load the partial view. `$.validator.unobtrusive.parse(document);`

Comment: Never versions: Be sure to load `jquery.validate.js` and `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` after JQuery (instead of `@Scripts.Render`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First add `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")` in your  `_Layout.cshtml` 
and after that add

```
$(function () {        
        $(document).ajaxComplete(function () {
            $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(document);
        });
    });
```

> for **parsing the unobtrusive attributes when we get content via ajax.**